# Cannot import tensorflow module and libtensorflow.so on linux x86

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, x86

I have a python code using tensorflow and also calling a C++ dll which need tensorflow dll.

The python run fine when I call only `import tensorflow as tf`, it also run fine when calling `tensorflowdll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libtensorflow.so')`.
But it fails when calling both, with the following error :

```
2023-11-27 12:03:24.354223: E tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:77] Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/core/op_expansion/node_counter
2023-11-27 12:03:24.354335: E tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:77] Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/core/op_expansion/graph_counter
2023-11-27 12:03:24.354369: E tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:77] Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/core/op_expansion/op_counter
2023-11-27 12:03:24.354437: F tensorflow/core/framework/device_factory.cc:90] Duplicate registration of device factory for type XLA_CPU with the same priority 50
```

I have no issue doing the same thing on Windows.

I tried with different tensorflow version from 2.4.0 to 2.11.0.

Comment: why are you calling them both?

Comment: calling both of these, registeres your cpu/gpu devices, and they can only be registered by one app/library at a time. which is why you are getting a "duplication" error

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I don't chose what the C++ dll needs, and it is also easier to code like that for the moment.
Ok but why is it ok to do it in Windows then ?

Comment: windows is a special child.

Comment: just pick one, and do as such, or add code which detects if its on windows or linux, and then run the respective import or ctype dll loader